# Cannot use underscore inside command in kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I need to issue a command `"python manage.py rebuild_index"` for rebuilding index of apache solr in my app deployment. But i get the following error:

```
The Deployment "test-app" is invalid: spec.template.spec.initContainers[5].name: Invalid value: "rebuild_index": a DNS-1123 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your error message I don't think the error is due to '_' in command, I guess you have named **initContainers name as well "rebuild_index"** that is where the error has been generated.

Object Name in k8s should be an alphanumeric character where only **"." and "-"** special characters are allowed. You can read more on this [documentation link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#names). **Please change the initContainer name to "rebuild-index"** which will resolve your issue.

Thanks,